# Saving data from other columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple tables set up with base prices for a number of select drop-downs. I am wanting to combine all those into one table after the user selects the prices they want. The problem I am having is I am using a number field (room) of each table to populate the number of drop-downs they can select.

**Table that's populating the drop-down**

```
id  room      area     pr_clean   pr_protectant   pr_sanitizer    pr_deodorizer
1   1        Area      8.95      19.95             17.95            7.5
2   2        Areas     17.9      39.9              35.9             15
3   3        Areas     26.85     59.85             53.85            22.5
4   4        Areas     35.8      79.8              71.8             30
5   5        Areas     39.95     99.75             89.75            37.5
6   6        Areas     53.7      119.7             107.7            45
7   Whole House Areas  69.95     139.65            125.65           52.5
```

**and the select drop-down is:**

```
<select name="rooms" id="Areas"> 
     <option value="" selected="selected">0</option>
          @foreach ($room as $rooms)
             <option data-price="{{ $rooms->pr_clean }}" value='{{ $rooms->room  }}'>{{ $rooms->room  }}</option>
          @endforeach
</select>


the data is saving like this via my php controller: 

                $input = [
                        Input::get('rooms')
                ];
//                 echo '<pre>';
//                var_dump($input); die;

                foreach($input as $services)
                {
                    $service = new Service();

                    $service->userID = $user->id;
                    $service->services = $services;

                    $service->save();
                }
```

Which is then saving into another table that collects all the data.

```
id  userID  services    price   created_at  updated_at
156 1           6     NULL  2013-09-08 01:14:26 2013-09-08 01:14:26
157 1           3     NULL  2013-09-08 01:14:26 2013-09-08 01:14:26
```

I need the services column and the price column to populate based on that value in the drop-down. Instead of the value itself going into the services column

Comment: how do you save? with a form? and you need to save to the price coloun the pr_clean coloun's value, and that value, which room was selected by the user?

Comment: Yes I am sorry for lack of that info. Yes it says as a form and then goes to the controller.. {{ Form::open(array('name' => 'services', 'action' => 'BookController@showServices'))}} ...yes basically I need "area" in the services column (based on the room column) and the price to save of course in the price column of the other table

Comment: if you use a form, there are to methods, get and post. So, if the user submit a form you need to get a $_GET or $_POST array, with the data of the all form elements, and that values. In your case if you use post method: $_POST['rooms'] and that gets a value. Now, if it is an uniqe, you can search in the SQL table for it, and read out the price. If not, create an onchange event to the select, and use one hide input the change event read out the data-price and put to the hide input element. I think, you can't get the data-* values on submit.